# What happens to ritual components when a ritual is cast?

Tags: magic, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

In Vampire the Masquerade, what happens to ritual components when the ritual is cast? Do they disappear, are they spent, or can they be used indefinitely?

Comment: Can you please use capitalization and punctuation in your question? It is really hard to read right now.

Comment: sorry about that, i was trying to ask that if a ritual has been succesfully cast, does the components used in the ritual can be reused. especially sympatetic components like a blood point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There is no indication for physical components

Some rituals would naturally destroy the components while they are performed, say snapping a small bone in half or swallowing a piece of coal. However these are usually quite easy to replace so it makes sense to let the player not worry about having a tally of how many splinters he has for in his bag - unless under extraordinary circumstances - strip-searched, imprisoned or in unusual environment.

### Blood points spent are spent for good

Whenever a Ritual (or anything else, really) calls you to "spend a blood point" this means it is not reclaimable and your character will have to drink blood to replenish his Vitae reserves. Rituals are no different. They do not rob you from your maximum Blood Potency, this stays the same and relative to your Generation. However, if you use a lot of Disciplines and Rituals you will have to hunt more. Finally, even if the ritual does not call for spilling or otherwise physically spoiling the blood, this represents using magical potential stored in vampire blood and any liquid that is left after the ritual is successful would be an inert substance that can only disgust and sicken the imbiber.

Comment: Some ritual components aren't so easy to replace.  Finding the 7th son of a 7th is hard, for example.  Rituals with exotic or hard-to-find components will have a description of the component in their rules.  For such things, STs may expect the player to call upon their resources (Contacts, Resources, spending Boons, etc), or roleplay the acquisition of new materials.  Common items, like a white ribbon or a candle, can be assumed to be readily available.

Comment: Losing the components might be a suitable consequence for a Botch, too.